# Cannot find correct stop valve size for toilet

Tags: toilet, valve

The stop valve to my cousin's toilet needs to be replaced.  It is a male threaded to the wall and 3/8 to supply line.

I took it out and took it to Home Depot to get a new one and they said they didn't have the size.  To get the size, I put the 7/8" end of the supply line the would screw onto the ballcock on the valve it and it looked like it would screw in.  But I cannot find a stop valve anywhere that is 7/8" x 3/8 (or any other).  No stop valves with 7/8.  Could I actually have what is being sold as a 5/8" inlet and need a 5/8 x 1/2 or 5/8 by 3/8?

I don't know if the confusion is due to mixing up the OD or the IPS of the valve. In other words, do they even make a stop valve with inlet 7/8 male thread?

I had to put it back on so we could turn the main water back on and I don't want to have to pull it off to measure it unless I just have to as it was hard to get back in due to cramped quarters for the toilet because I'll have to just put it back until a part arrives from the Internet as no one locally has that size...whichever it is.

If they don't make 7/8 stop valves, then I must have a 5/8 valve, right? It was larger than the 1/2" threaded valves they sell at Home Depot. If I do need to pull it off and measure it, what do I measure?  The inside or out to the threads?

I wanted to cut the valve off and put a Sharkbite valve on the 1/2" copper line but I don't think there is enough pipe coming out of the wall to get the Sharkbite on correctly.

Comment: Pipe and fittings are all sold by the inside diameter of the pipe.

Comment: is the copper coming out the wall finished with a soldered fitting prior to the valve? If you are concerned about length you could heat the joint to remove the fitting and reinstall a new standard fitting or compression valve which is more common at least in my area

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this without having to understand the exact dimensions of your fitting or the way sizes are named.  ID, OD, trade size, nominal size, copper, brass, NPT .... when a homeowner is repairing one old fitting all those things may as well be random.

You're lucky you can remove the fitting!

Way 1:  Take it to a good plumbing supply shop.  They will figure it out for you and sell you the right part or combination of parts that will work.

Way 2: Take it to your big hardware store.  If they sell the correct replacement they will also sell threaded male nipples or other bits that will fit properly inside yours.  First, look for any threaded pipe or connector that fits nicely into yours.  THAT will tell you the correct nominal sizing of what you need to buy.  Put that back and find your fitting in the right size.

Comment: Many hardware stores have a bank of "demo" connectors that you can try out your part on.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got odd sizes, you may need to buy an adapter or two.

Get a new stop valve that will fit the supply line to the toilet, then an adapter that will adjust sizes to make the new valve fit whatever size/thread is on the wall.

It's called "cobbling it together" and sometimes, that's just what you've got to do.